# Opening multiple datepicker inside div in one page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my link jquery [datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/cqbwrp29/).  It does not open when there are more than two datepickers.  It open when only one.

```
<div>
<label>
Datepicker 1
</label>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<div>
</div id="datepicker1">
</div>
<div>
<label>
Datepicker 2
</label>
<input type="text" id="input2">
<div>
</div id="datepicker2">
</div>
<div>
<label>
From
</label>
<input type="text" id="input3">
<label>
To
</label>
<input type="text" id="input4">
<div>
</div id="datepicker3">
</div>
```

Comment: which one you looking for? jquery datepicker or normal html datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use jquery date picker or normal html date picker
```

**using jquery**

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    $("#datepicker1").change(function() {
            $("#span1").html($("#datepicker1").val());
    });
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").change(function() {
            $("#span2").html($("#datepicker2").val());
    });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>

<p>From :<span id="span1"></span></p>
<p>To :<span id="span2"></span></p>

 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**using html date control**

```html
<input type="date"/>
<input type="date"/>
<input type="date"/>
<input type="date"/>
```

Comment: in my case, I need to bind it to a div or span element

Comment: i have updated the code. you can use '$("#datepicker1").change(function() {
           
    });' function

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion does not apply to my case.  my case datepicker is tied with div element not tied with inout element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change you **JavaScript code**, It will works for you...

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#input1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#input2" ).datepicker();
    $( "#input3" ).datepicker();
    $( "#input4" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
```

Change ID accordingly..